# How to display from current month and year in date picker to restrict showing previous year and month android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am using custom date picker where i am using like this.

```
public class DatePickersDialog extends DatePickerDialog implements OnDateChangedListener {

    private DatePickerDialog mDatePicker;

     public DatePickersDialog(Context context, OnDateSetListener callBack,
            int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        super(context,callBack, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
       mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(context,callBack, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
       mDatePicker.getDatePicker().init(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, this);
        updateTitle(year, monthOfYear);

    }
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year,
        int month, int day) {
    updateTitle(year, month);
    }
    private void updateTitle(int year, int month) {
        Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        mDatePicker.setTitle(getFormat().format(mCalendar.getTime()));

    }  
    public DatePickerDialog getPicker(){
        return this.mDatePicker;
    }

    public SimpleDateFormat getFormat(){
    return new SimpleDateFormat("MMM, yyyy");
    };   

   }
Utils.class 


public static DatePickerDialog customDatePickers(Activity activity, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener) {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int cardYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int cardMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int cardDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    DatePickersDialog datePickersDialog = new DatePickersDialog(activity,datePickerListener,cardYear,cardMonth,cardDay);
    Date minDate = new Date();
    c.set(cardYear, cardMonth, cardDay - 1, 0, 0);
    minDate.setTime(c.getTimeInMillis());
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = datePickersDialog.getPicker();

    try {
        Field[] datePickerDialogFields = datePickerDialog.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field datePickerDialogField : datePickerDialogFields) {
            if (datePickerDialogField.getName().equals("mDatePicker")) {
                datePickerDialogField.setAccessible(true);
                DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) datePickerDialogField.get(datePickerDialog);
                Field datePickerFields[] = datePickerDialogField.getType()
                        .getDeclaredFields();
                for (Field datePickerField : datePickerFields) {
                    if ("mDayPicker".equals(datePickerField.getName()) || "mDaySpinner".equals(datePickerField.getName())) {
                        datePickerField.setAccessible(true);
                        Object dayPicker = new Object();
                        dayPicker = datePickerField.get(datePicker);
                        ((View) dayPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        datePickerDialog.show();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return datePickerDialog;
}

 scanExpireDate = (CheckoutEditText) findViewById(R.id.scan_expire_date);
scanExpireDate.setTextView();



public void onDatePickerClick(View view){
            Utils.customDatePicker(this, datePickerListener);
    }
```

But it displays like this below pic. showing previous year and month. How to restrict that?
[image]

How to solove this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set its bounds using:

```
setMinDate(long minDate)
setMaxDate(long maxDate)
```

Where the argument is the usual number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 in the default time zone. You'll still have to calculate these values of course, but that should be trivial to do with the Calendar class: just take the current date and add or substract x years.

EDIT:
You can get the underlying DatePicker from a DatePickerDialog (by simply calling getDatePicker()) or in your code I think it's where you call DatePicker datePicker and just add rows like:

```
datePicker.setMinDate(<long variable>);
```

Comment: hi..thanks for your answer. will you please tell where to use this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using this in custom date picker. Hope it might help for someone

DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = datePickersDialog.getPicker();
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minDate.getTime());